# Apache Lucene or another Search in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, lucene, search-engine

I would like to implement a search functionality within my iPhone app which can search for terms within all the documents in the application.

I believe I cannot use Apache Lucene directly since it is in Java. Can I use Lucy which is a C port of Lucene (not sure if Perl and Ruby would work on it)?

Or is there any other open-source search engine which I can use in my iPhone app for search within the app?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am also looking for an answer.

Comment: Not really... Didn't pursue this further.

Answer (score 5):

you can use sqlite3 with it's fts3 - full text search engine. Requires nothing, embedded database. Iphone also uses it internally.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Objective-C port of Lucene - [LuceneKit](http://github.com/tcurdt/lucenekit). Mac OS has [SearchKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/SearchKit/Reference/reference.html), not sure if it is available for iPhone.

I haven't tried out either of these. So, my knowledge is only academic.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're doing, but indexing and searching are relatively resource intensive operations.  You might be better off building a server application that handles the full-text search and your iPhone app can communicate with it.